# Can't get into my new phone

Tags: hardware

Recently I purchased an android phone from my local second hand store and they showed me It was working but when I got home and I tested it out it would not let me use it because it said I had to sign in with the previous owners account. How do I sign in with my account?

Thanks,
Asher.

Comment: Just return to that store and ask them a refund! The phone is still linked to the previous owner's account you can't put yours! If you want to bypass that , google for FRP bypass + your phone model

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get into Settings, most phones have a way to factory reset with hardware buttons. You can probably find it with some googling.

If it's a Samsung phone, depending on the model, you can use Smart Switch to do an "Emergency software recovery and initialization", which completely reinstalls the phone's most recent software and firmware. Maybe other brands have something similar.

Comment: This won't work simply because the phone has FRP enabled! Did you understand what OP said?